# How to get the API document for admob-sdk-android.jar?

Tags: javascript, android, sdk, admob

I have downloaded the admob-sdk-android.jar for creating AdMob applications. How/where to get the API documents for this particular SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer basic documentation here:

http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

Also I am sure that you can't download a single jar file, instead they allows us to download an archieve file which contains jar file and also you can check for the `javadoc` and `pdf` instructions file in the archieved file.

Comment: vikas, can i get the API documents like javaSDK or androidSDK for this admob-sdk-jar?

Comment: @yokks:`admob-sdk-android.jar` is the file you need to add in your project and it dosent contains documents you want, instead you can download a zip file from your AdMob site after adding an application in your account. And in that zip file you can get the `javadoc` and `admob-sdk-android.jar` and some `samples`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out what appears to be their official webpage?

http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

Edit: Gah, too slow. http://www.admob.com/docs/AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf is the direct link to the instructions.

Comment: klaus,can i get the API documents like javaSDK or androidSDK for this admob-sdk-jar?

Comment: Come on now. The .pdf mentions a JavaDoc - you probably have some silly version which doesn't include it. http://www.admob.com/register go there, go through the official process and get the actual version. I'm sure you'll get it.